# Do you get one or two saves when pushed into a pit?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement

Does a character get one or two saves when pushed into a pit by Forced Movement?

Reading the Rules Compendium, one is one mentioned in the section on Hindering Terrain, p.207,  and another in **Catching Oneself** on p.212

Are they talking about the same Saving Throw, or do you get a second chance ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The character gets one** (and only one) saving throw.

The two sections you noted are referring to the same saving throw.

On page 207, the Hindering Terrain -> Saving Throw section ends with

> See "Forced Movement" and "Teleportation" discussed later in this section

Page 212 is within the Forced Movement section and contains the details about how to resolve the saving throw mentioned on 207.

Comment: So one saving throw for the Forced Movement and if you fail and the said forced movement leads you to fall...you're automatically screwed? Logic wise I would disagree

Comment: @MrJinPengyou - Are you aware that forced movement does not normally allow a saving throw?  If the forced movement forces you into hindering terrain (a pit is an example of hindering terrain) then you get a saving throw to avoid going into the hidden terrain.

Comment: @patludwig Thanks Pat ... I thought it was one, but it's good to get a second opinion